# .htaccess rewrite rule without parameter for php file

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Something is wrong in my htaccess file , i want a simple rewrite rule for login.php,change login.php into l13.I wrote htaccess rewrite rule like as

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^l13     login.php
```

but l13 is not working instead of login.php

Answer (score 1):

Tried this, works for me:

```
RewriteRule ^l13(/?)$     login.php [L]
```

Make sure that mod_rewrite is enabled, and [L] is required to stop evaluating other rules (in case you have more of them below)

Comment: it works but it open other file instead of login.php